# Error NaN al sumar distintos resultados

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una función donde se calcule el valor de 1 producto por la cantidad de productos que necesite el "cliente", y muestre los colores que el cliente elija para su producto, se muestra un **input** de "Cantidad" y otro de "Color", en **cantidad de autos** se muestra la cantidad que eligió el cliente, en **Precio Total** se muestra la multiplicación del precio del producto X la cantidad escogida y en **Color escogido** muestra el color que escriba el cliente, hasta ahí me funciona bien.

Luego el objetivo es sumar el precio total de los resultados de cada uno en **Valor Total** que es donde me sale el error NaN, luego de varios intentos al sumar me sigue saliendo el error NaN.

Espero que se haya entendido y me puedan ayudar.

```js
//Debemos calcular el precio total de varios productos indicando cantidad y color

//Precio de los autos
var precioMaserati = 57000000;
var precioMacklaren = 110000000;
var precioLamborghini = 118000000;

//Identificamos la cantidad de autos elegidos por marca de vehiculo
var cantidadInputMas = document.querySelector("input[class='input-maserati']");
var cantidadInputMack = document.querySelector("input[class='input-macklaren']");
var cantidadInputLambo = document.querySelector("input[class='input-lambo']");

//Identificamos el color de autos elegidos por marca de vehiculo
var colorInputMas = document.querySelector("input[class='input-color-1']");
var colorInputMack = document.querySelector("input[class='input-color-2']");
var colorInputLambo = document.querySelector("input[class='input-color-3']");

//Información de Maserati
var cantidadFinalMAs = document.querySelector(".total-de-maserati")
var precioFinalMAs = document.querySelector(".total-price-maserati")
var colorFinalMAs = document.querySelector(".color-car-1")

//Información de Macklaren
var cantidadFinalMack = document.querySelector(".total-de-macklaren")
var precioFinalMack = document.querySelector(".total-price-macklaren")
var colorFinalMack = document.querySelector(".color-car-2")

//Información de Lambo
var cantidadFinalLambo = document.querySelector(".total-de-lambo")
var precioFinalLambo = document.querySelector(".total-price-lambo")
var colorFinalLambo = document.querySelector(".color-car-3")

function calcularTotalMas() {
    var cantidadMaserati = cantidadInputMas.value
    var colormaserati = colorInputMas.value

    cantidadFinalMAs.innerHTML = cantidadMaserati;
    precioFinalMAs.innerHTML = (precioMaserati * cantidadMaserati).toLocaleString();
    colorFinalMAs.style.backgroundColor = colormaserati;
}

function calcularTotalMack() {
    var cantidadMacklaren = cantidadInputMack.value
    var colorMacklaren = colorInputMack.value

    cantidadFinalMack.innerHTML = cantidadMacklaren;
    precioFinalMack.innerHTML = (precioMacklaren * cantidadMacklaren).toLocaleString();
    colorFinalMack.style.backgroundColor = colorMacklaren;
}

function calcularTotalLambo() {
    var cantidadLambo = cantidadInputLambo.value
    var colorLambo = colorInputLambo.value

    cantidadFinalLambo.innerHTML = cantidadLambo;
    precioFinalLambo.innerHTML = (precioLamborghini * cantidadLambo).toLocaleString();
    colorFinalLambo.style.backgroundColor = colorLambo;
}

var precioTotal = document.querySelector(".price-cars");
//var cantidadTotal = document.querySelector(".mount-cars")

function calcularTotalAutos() {
    let calPrecioTotal = (precioFinalMAs = document.querySelector(".total-price-maserati")).value + (precioFinalMack = document.querySelector(".total-price-macklaren")).value + (precioFinalLambo = document.querySelector(".total-price-lambo")).value;

    precioTotal.innerHTML = calPrecioTotal;
}
```

```css
.colors {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
}

.colors div {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Ejercicio JS 3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="card-section">
            <div class="card card-1">
                <h6>Maserati</h6>
                <div>
                    <input type="number" class="input-maserati" placeholder="Cantidad de autos">
                </div>
        
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="input-color-1" placeholder="Color del auto">
                </div>
        
                <p>Precio: $57.000.000</p>
        
                <div class="card-boton">
                    <button onclick="calcularTotalMas()">Calcular Precio</button>
                </div>

                <p>Cantidad de Autos: <span class="total-de-maserati"></span></p>
                <p>Precio Total: $<span class="total-price-maserati"></span></p>
                <div class="colors">
                    <p>Color elegido:</p>
                    <div class="color-car-1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

--------------o-----------------

            <div class="card card-2">
                <h6>Macklaren</h6>
                <div>
                    <input type="number" class="input-macklaren" placeholder="Cantidad de autos">
                </div>
        
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="input-color-2" placeholder="Color del auto">
                </div>
        
                <p>Precio: $110.000.000</p>
        
                <div class="card-boton">
                    <button onclick="calcularTotalMack()">Calcular Precio</button>
                </div>

                <p>Cantidad de Autos: <span class="total-de-macklaren"></span></p>
                <p>Precio Total: $<span class="total-price-macklaren"></span></p>
                <div class="colors">
                    <p>Color elegido:</p>
                    <div class="color-car-2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

--------------o-----------------

            <div class="card card-3">
                <h6>Lamborghini</h6>
                <div>
                    <input type="number" class="input-lambo" placeholder="Cantidad de autos">
                </div>
        
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="input-color-3" placeholder="Color del auto">
                </div>
        
                <p>Precio: $118.000.000</p>
        
                <div class="card-boton">
                    <button onclick="calcularTotalLambo()">Calcular Precio</button>
                </div>

                <p>Cantidad de Autos: <span class="total-de-lambo"></span></p>
                <p>Precio Total: $<span class="total-price-lambo"></span></p>
                <div class="colors">
                    <p>Color elegido:</p>
                    <div class="color-car-3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

--------------o-----------------

        <div class="total-section">
            <p>Valor Total: $<span class="price-cars"></span></p>
            
            <div class="card-boton">
                <button onclick="calcularTotalAutos()">Calcular Valor Total</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En la función de valor total, aplicales un parseInt a los valores que vayas a sumar, algo asi como "parseInt(document.querySelector(".total-price-maserati")).value) + ..."

Answer (score 1):

Veo como sugieren el uso de parseInt, pero simplemente...

¿Por que no realizar bien el calculo dentro de la función y ya?

Tienes los precios, y las cantidades en los inputs ya.. solo realiza el calculo directo creo que seria mas simple.

```
function calcularTotalAutos() {
  var maserati = precioMaserati * cantidadInputMas.value;
  var mclaren = precioMacklaren * cantidadInputMack.value;
  var lambo = precioLamborghini * cantidadInputLambo.value;
  var calPrecioTotal = maserati + mclaren + lambo;
  precioTotal.innerHTML = calPrecioTotal.toLocaleString();
}
```

*btw, es mclaren, sin la k :3*

En el sgte ejemplo, es 1-maserati, 2-mclaren y 3-lambos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]